# unit testing directive and isolatedScope not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive

I am trying to unit test a directive that was previously written and for my first unit test all I want to do is check a variable inside the scope of the directive.

However, every time I try to run the method `isolatedScope()` on my html element, I receive the error `elem.isolatedScope is not a function`.

One of the strange things is, when I set a breakpoint just after I run `$compile` on my element, from the javascript console, I am able to print the directives isolated scope.

Trying to set my `isolatedScope` to a variable like below, will always result in the error `elem.isolatedScope is not a function`.

```
describe('directive: wikis', function() {
    var $scope, elem, isolated;

    beforeEach(module('app'));

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_, _$rootScope_){
        $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();

        elem = angular.element('<wikis></wikis>');
        elem = _$compile_(elem)($scope);
        isolated = elem.isolatedScope()
        isolated.$digest();
    }));

    describe('$scope should be defined', function(){
        it('data should be empty object', function() {
            expect(isolated.data).to.be.null;
        });
    });
});
```

Any idea on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: isolateScope was deprecated (angular 1.3?) so it won't work unless you're using an early version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It is `isolateScope`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#methods), not `isolatedScope`.

*Isolate scope* and *isolated scope* terms can be used interchangeably, but the first one [is preferred in official sources](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive) (it was likely coined by one of the framework authors):

> What we want to be able to do is separate the scope inside a directive
>   from the scope outside, and then map the outer scope to a directive's
>   inner scope. We can do this by creating what we call **an isolate
>   scope**.

Comment: Thank you. smh that has been an issue for me for far to long.